# Maven prefixing WEB-INF/classes into JAR dependency

Tags: maven-3, spring-boot

> Update: Solved! Posted solution as my own answer. Will be accepting it in two days when I'm allowed to.

## A little back story

I've been chasing down this rabbit hole for the past few days, and my question has drastically changed shape over that time. Initially, I thought I had an issue with `Spring Boot`, because it failed to parse one of my `@Configuration` annotated classes. Debugging that, I determined that Spring was looking in all the right places for one of my `JAR`-bound dependencies, but was coming up with a `FileNotFoundException` when trying to load a class from the `JAR`.

I was thrown off by this, because the `JAR` in question was quite verifiably on the classpath. I could print out the classpath during app startup, and see my `JAR` living nice and cozy inside.

So I simplified. And simplified. Eventually, I got things down to a project with two Java source files, and a tiny placeholder `JAR` pulled through `Maven`. This `JAR` only contains one file: `tiny/jar/BaseTest.class`.

This worked perfectly. From there, I swapped the dependency `JAR` on this small project. . . and startup failed. So I compared the `JARs` and noticed something odd.

## The realization

While my small `JAR` contained a folder hierarchy of:

```
tiny/jar/BaseTest.class
```

The larger `JAR` looked like:

```
WEB-INF/classes/com/company/...
```

This `WEB-INF/classes` prefix is the poison which is killing `Spring Boot`'s class loader. It expects to find classes starting from the root:  `com/company/...` -- no prefix allowed.

I believe that Maven's dependency management is doing something tricky here. When my `JAR` is created using the `clean install` goal, it has the `com/company/...` root inside of it. If I manually copy this version of the `JAR` into my servers `WEB-INF/lib` folder, everything works, recognizes, and fires up perfectly.

But when Maven is used to bring in the dependency, `WEB-INF/classes` is prefixed on to my folder hierarchy, breaking everything.

## The question

Does anyone know how I can prevent Maven from altering the directory structure of my `JAR`? The `JAR` is 100% correct until Maven pulls it in as a dependency, and suddenly the `WEB-INF/classes` prefix appears.

Here are the three `POM` files for reference. I've cut out a large swath of dependencies, but left everything else intact for easier reading.

#### Tiny Jar POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>tiny</groupId>
<artifactId>jar</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<name>jar</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

#### Big Jar POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>company-foundation</artifactId>
<version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> <!--  Sonar -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <!-- To use snapshots, you must also use the Sonatype Snapshots respository -->
    <repository>
       <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
       <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

#### Project POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>dependency-issue</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>jar-dependency-issue</name>
<description>Barebones Spring Boot project used to demonstrate a JAR loading issue.</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>demo.JarDependencyIssueApplication</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- To run on a separate server, we need to mark tomcat starter as provided. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-foundation</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>tiny</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: So.. what would be inside your "big jar" now if you run "mvn package" ? It's not really clear to me what might have happened here--could the pom for that project ever have specified war packaging? Might someone have renamed that war to jar? If what is currently produced by "mvn package" looks correct when you inspect it, then maybe you'll be ok doing "mvn install" to replace the previous, incorrectly generated artifact. Just a thought..

Comment: The 'big jar' contains four folders when packaged with Maven: `templates/`, `META-INF/`, `config/`, and `com/`  Which is perfect. When I pull it in as a maven dependency to a second project, everything breaks. I need the Maven dependency to not have `/WEB-INF/classes` prefixed before `com/` --- No-one but me is touching this project right now, but eventually the 'big' dependency will be the base for a number of projects. Do you know how to prevent Maven from adding the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder structure to a `JAR` which previously only contained the four folders listed above?

Comment: Ok. Sounds like you just need to replace the one that your main "Project POM" is picking up from the repository with the one that you can now correctly build with "mvn package". Am thinking if you simply issue "mvn install" against the "big jar" project, you will replace the incorrectly generated artifact with the one that should meet your needs now. Does it make sense?

Comment: I've done a `clean install` of my package dozens of times through this process. I can look in my `.m2` folder, and the `JAR` in there is correct. There's not a problem with the JAR dependency until it is pulled in to my sub-project.

Comment: Have seen some odd behavior with Maven before, but this isn't one of them (adding /WEB-INF/classes).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/DAGg7ZA.png This is what my big `JAR` looks like in the `.m2` folder. It also looks like this in the `target/` folder within its own project. When I pull it in as a dependency for another project, though, suddenly the root folder becomes `WEB-INF/`, `classes/` is put beneath that, and THEN what is pictured is placed inside `classes/`

Comment: Could Maven be finding the problematic jar in another repository?? Not clear how it could be getting loused up if the jar you are installing has the correct structure. Maybe bump the version number so as to be sure this is currently happening and not an artifact of an earlier experimentation. BTW, you did exactly the right thing to boil the problem down to barest bones!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71608/discussion-between-unigeek-and-seth-ellison).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem! I just got done poring over the configuring of my projects, comparing them for any suspicious deviations. Turns out that my larger `JAR`s project in `Eclipse` had its `Deployment Assembly` (Found under Properties > Deployment Assembly) set to:

Source ============ Deploy Path

`src/main/java` --------> `/WEB-INF/classes`

`src/main/resources` -> `/WEB-INF/classes`

This caused my server to deploy the `JAR` into an internal `/WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Changing the `Deploy Path` setting to `/` fixed the problem! Everything is working perfectly now! Woo!

Comment: LOL. Why did I think you were using Maven to create your artifacts? Glad you found it.

Comment: Guess that was an m2eclipse thing.. didn't realize that was part of the equation.

Comment: Yeah, I was using a version of Maven built in to the Spring Tool Suite. It didn't occur me to look into the IDE-specific configuration until I was entirely out of Maven-specific settings to investigate. Once I started looking through project settings, I realized that the IDE had a say in the packaging of JARs. The solution followed soon after. Thanks again for your time man. You helped me shift away from suspecting Maven when you, too, were stumped.

Comment: Hah, thanks me. Ran into this issue again today after overhauling my dev  tools. Issue felt familiar, so I checked my question history, and what do you know, there's an answer from me, for me.